# Grafana Annotation/Variable Position On Screen

Tags: json, grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-alerts, jsonmodel

[Annotation/Variable Default Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krMyn.png)    <----- Screenshot

I want to find a way to move grafana annotations/variable position on dashboard. Issue is - there will be a lot more annotations and variables, and it will look cluttered. I want to find a way to organize it and make it more eye pleasing. Open for all suggestions!

Tried looking for plugins that would help with organizing these things - didn't find one.
Tried playing around JSON model specifically under

```
 {
  "annotations":{
     "list": []
```

Tried using these blocks on it but failed miserably -

```
      "gridPos": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "w": 12,
      "h": 9
    },
```

and

```
{
  "annotations": {
    "list": [
      {
        "x": 100,
        "y": 10
      }.`
```

I am expecting either a plugin solution for this issue or an answer that says that it's possible to achieve what i am doing in the JSON model. Or any other solution!